# How safe is it to enable unprivileged user namespace: unprivileged_userns_clone

Tags: linux, container

Linux [user namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html) are special, as they play the role of the owner of the other namespaces.

Distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, Arch, ...) seem to ship with unprivileged user namespaces disabled.

For example, when [podman](https://podman.io/) is run as non-root user and unprivileged user namespaces are disabled, one gets a notice like this:

> user namespaces are not enabled in /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone

It is easy to [enable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303213/how-to-enable-user-namespaces-in-the-kernel-for-unprivileged-unshare) unprivileged user namespaces.

In which context it would be safe to enable them?

Comment: Your premise disagrees with my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. `$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone
1
`. I can create a user namespace: `$ unshare -Ur
#`

Comment: Confirmed, it seems the defaults have changes [over time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303214/376).

Comment: Very unsafe... Unprivileged userns is a boon for exploits.